# Connecting remote Dgraph database from App written in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, dgraph

I'm new to Swift but no so new to PHP, yet I have problem finding any instructions on how to connect to a remote Dgraph database, located on AWS. 
Any direction to a tutorial about how to get data from that type of DB would be appreciated.

I tried to google the problem, but Dgraph being new its not so well supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTP API https://docs.dgraph.io/clients/#raw-http
You can do all procedures via HTTP.